# Swift playground prints parentheses

Tags: xcode, swift

Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.0:
The code below prints "15 ()" in the debug area.  I would have expected it to print "15 1".  Why are the parentheses being printed?

```
var n = 15
print(n, n /= 10)
```

Comment: If you have an "unexpected" result: 1) Use a compiled project instead, the diagnostic messages are sometimes better. – 2) Split the expression into separate steps. In your case: `let foo = n /= 10` which results in *"warning: constant 'foo' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected"*. – 3) Command-click on the `/=` operator in Xcode, which shows that it does not return a value.

Comment: Good advice, except that is this case the diagnostic message simply says that the unexpected result "may be unexpected"!

Comment: What I meant is  `inferred to have type '()'` ...

Comment: Ah!  I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is nothing returned from an assignment operator. 
It is still executed though.

See docs here: [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> The assignment operator (=) does not return a value, to prevent it
>   from being mistakenly used when the equal to operator (==) is
>   intended.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the `n /= 15` expression returns a `Void`, because the `/=` operator returns `Void` in Swift. We can see that from it's declaration:

```
public func /=<T : _IntegerArithmeticType>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T)
```

And because in Swift, `Void` is an alias for the empty tuple:

```
/// The empty tuple type.
///
/// This is the default return type of functions for which no explicit
/// return type is specified.
public typealias Void = ()
```

the second argument/expression passed to `print` gets printed as `()`.

Comment: This is the better answer for this question.

Comment: That's very generous of you.  However, there was sufficient information in your answer for me to infer what was happening.  (In fact, I actually inferred the answer from a comment added to a still earlier but incorrect answer.  That answer was then deleted, taking the comment with it.)  The later answer, that you're referring to, is indeed better but may have been derived from your answer.  If so, should it be awarded the credit?  This is all more complicated than I expected!

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan if Michael's post answered your question then you don't need to change anything to the state of the question. If you found my answer useful, then you can up-vote it. There's no need for further actions.